Copy Linux Mint boot area from external SSD drive
I'm sorry if this question is not on topic. I am moving from Windows to Linux and had the idea to use a bootable Linux Mint external SSD to slowly download and integrate all the software I use, while at the same time using Windows as my daily driver. Once I am comfortable with Linux, I will then discard windows and use Linux Mint as my daily driver.
I will then need to clone the bootable Linux Mint on to my main SSD. Would Clonezilla allow me to clone the bootable SSD on to my main SSD and use the rest of the allocated space on my drive as free space for Linux Mint?

It's a notebook? If you are new to Linux maybe an easier solution is to install Mint alongside with Windows, in the same disk, reducing the Win partition. At boot GRUB will let you choose your OS. Always backup of everything!

I must agree with the previous comment. You can dual-boot or, if you intend to use Linux from now on but you occasionally need a given Windows program, then use Windows in a virtual machine. Also any Linux distro takes very little time to install, less than what you want to do which is a bad idea to start with.

Well, I hope that Mint uses LVM by default (or at least provide an option in its installer), otherwise after discard windows the OP may need to perform the worst -- moving a partition, in order to use the regained space flexibly. (While reinstalling Linux takes much less effort and time when compared with Windows, it doesn't mean that it is necessarily easy / won't be a hassle, especially for newbs.)

I use Kubuntu on external SSD that is copy of my Kubuntu on main working desktop. External drive if SSD works very well. I would never clone it to HDD, but do a new install & restore from backup. Restore would include /home, list of installed apps, and then any data partition(s). If system files changed, copy those from /etc. I edit grub, but since that is about all, I just copy those files into /home so part of normal backup.

Guys, I want to use it as a daily driver I don't want to dual boot. Like I said I'm moving away from windows. @oldfred that's an idea. So I could setup my Mint on the bootable device to my liking and then when I'm ready flash Mint on to my main internal SSD and then just restore the data from the usb?

Best to keep a backup of Windows. We regularly find users to totally convert to Linux, but then find one app or game that only runs in Windows and wants to restore Windows. I have Windows laptop only for tax software & travel. And use external SSD when traveling. My main install is on desktop & I connect external to desktop & rsync /home settings & data to SSD. Only issues are desktop has large screen but laptop does not, so I have to change font defaults and few other settings.

That's great advice. Yes, I will keep a backup of windows going forward. I had already thought to do that. IThat will definitely not be the case with me. Any thing that I need (for work, etc..) I will use a virtual machine with Windows on it. So how would you advise me to backup my bootable linux drive before I restore it on to my internal SSD? The software that comes with Linux? I guess it would be different for me from Kubuntu?

I/we don't advise doing that at all. Simply install it where you want and when you want. If you need to ask how to clone a drive then you shouldn't do it for anything important, before you fully understand all the ins and outs of the process and all the requirements, end of story. It's better to do it twice correctly if you must than wasting time trying to move it to the internal drive, potentially ending up with an unbootable system, wasting the same time as new installation that you'll end up doing as well if it fails.

@ChanganAuto fair enough. So cloning is out of the picture. What about the previous answer from oldfred? There wouldn't be much harm in running a bootable Mint drive importing all my apps/settings and then once I have installed Mint to my internal drive, do a backup of the bootable Mint and restore it on to my internal drive. That's good, right?

Yes, using resync is a nice idea.
